# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.OpenJpaVendorAdapter

Tags: java, spring, jpa

upgrading spring from 3.x to 5.x(5.3.17).

getting this exception:
Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.OpenJpaVendorAdapter#e0ffa44' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.OpenJpaVendorAdapter] while setting bean property 'jpaVendorAdapter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.OpenJpaVendorAdapter] for bean with name 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.OpenJpaVendorAdapter#e0ffa44' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/xxxx.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

tried to add org.hibernate.javax.persistence", name: "hibernate-jpa-2.1-api", version: "1.0.0.Final" in gradle file. But same error exists

Comment: You are using OpenJPA **not** Hibernate, so trying to add Hibernate dependencies won't fix it. Apparently in your previous application you used OpenJPA which isn't supported, either use EclipseLink or Hibernate. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58024654/spring-boot-2-1-7-with-openjpavendoradapter (a similar question about Spring Boot/Spring 5 with OpenJPA).

Comment: See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20584 this similar to what you are facing.

Comment: Thanks for the support.
I have upgraded openjpa to version 3.2.2. 
Previously in my code org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.OpenJpaVendorAdaptor is used as a bean.
Instead of that what adaptor should we need to use.?